# openssl pkcs12 -export Programmatically

Tags: ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

I was wondering if there is a way to access the pkcs12 command of openssl **programmatically**.

I intend to access the export functionality of the pkcs12 command using a (any) programming language. My current installation is on Python.

I am aware of the fact that there is a command line interface to pkcs12 but that requires  starting a new sub - process which is not feasible for the problem that I have.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the [PyOpenSSL PKCS#12](http://pythonhosted.org/pyOpenSSL/api/crypto.html#pkcs12-objects) module should be useful for this.

In Java, you could load the PKCS#12 file directly as a `PKCS12` KeyStore and then get the private key. You may also find [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)'s `PEMWriter` useful to export the keys or certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This answer points to a related sample code in C :
[how to verify a P12 certificate using openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750533/how-to-verify-a-p12-certificate-using-openssl/7385746#7385746)

Function and class names should be similar in Python.