# how to verify a P12 certificate using openssl?

Tags: c, openssl, x509certificate, verification

Can anyone tell me how to verify the Password-based P12 file using openssl? Logic or sample code will be much helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a code sample that :
 - opens a pkcs#12 file with password
 - extracts the private key and certificates

in the openssl source code at :

```
./demos/pkcs12/pkread.c
```

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/pkcs12/pkread.c